# Multiple direct to S3 Image Uploads in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I followed [this Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) to direct upload images in Rails with S3.

My implementation works well. However, I dynamically add fields with the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), containing image upload fields. Thus, my goal is to be able to upload multiple images using Heroku's method for direct upload.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
      var fileInput    = $(elem);
      var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
      var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
      var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
      var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
      fileInput.after(barContainer);
      fileInput.fileupload({
        fileInput:       fileInput,
        url:             form.data('url'),
        type:            'POST',
        autoUpload:       true,
        formData:         form.data('form-data'),
        paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
        dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
        replaceFileInput: false,
        progressall: function (e, data) {
          var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
          progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
        },
        start: function (e) {
          submitButton.prop('disabled', true);
          insertedItem.find('#validate_image').css('opacity', '0.3');
          insertedItem.find('#validate_image').prop('disabled', true);
          progressBar.
            css('background', '#11D26F').
            css('display', 'block').
            css('width', '0%').
            text("Loading...");
        },
        done: function(e, data) {
          submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
          insertedItem.find('#validate_image').css('opacity', '1');
          insertedItem.find('#validate_image').prop('disabled', false);
          progressBar.text("Uploading done");

          // extract key and generate URL from response
          var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
          var url   = 'https://' + form.data('host') + '/' + key;

          // create hidden field
          var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
          form.append(input);
        },
        fail: function(e, data) {
          submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
          if (data['messages']['uploadedBytes'] == 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size') {
            progressBar.
              css("background", "red").
              text("Uploaded file is too big (max 3.5 MB)");
          }
          else {
            progressBar.
              css("background", "red").
              text("Failed");
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

The problem is, each time I upload a new file, it adds an hidden field at the end of the form with the same image url. I would like to generate each time a new url for the uploaded image.

I searched a solution for hours and couldn't find one. Any idea how I could do using the Heroku method?

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I hacked my way like this:
Since I only want to upload max 10 images, I generated 10 different presigned_posts:

```
def set_s3_direct_post
      @s3_direct_post1 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post2 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post3 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post4 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post5 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post6 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post7 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post8 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post9 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
      @s3_direct_post10 = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', content_length_range: 0..3500000)
    end
```

Then I moved the form data to my dynamically generated container with some javascript.

It works!

Comment: Please share your code for this? Im trying to figure out the same thing but I am stuck :-(